# Why does some code work HackerRank but not Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, while-loop

The code below works fine on HackerRank, but not on Xcode 11. I suspect the while loops are causing the issue. Is there something I am missing?

This is not the first time code works on HackerRank, but not Xcode. I usually work on Xcode before submitting it to learn. I would like to make sure the code I write on Xcode will work on any compiler.
I would appreciate some insight.

```
int main(){
    int n, i=0;
    cin >> n;

    int * A = new int[n];

    while(cin >> A[i++]);
    while(cout << A[--n] << ':' && n);
    delete[]A;
    return 0;
}
```

The question is:
User will need to enter the size of an array and the elements of the array on the same line separate by a space. The program will return the array in reverse order.

sample input: 4 (enter)

sample input: 1 2 3 4 (enter)

sample output: 4 3 2 1

When I try running on Xcode it seems to loop forever after I manually input the values. The cursor just blinks. I have to force quit. I do not get any errors. See image in the link below.
[Xcode debug area image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fifqG.png)

Comment: Please describe how it does not work.  Do you get an error?  Do you get the wrong results?

Comment: Thank you for quick support, I have updated the question. Hopefully its more clear.

Comment: `while(cout << A[--n] << ':' && n);` -- Are you trying to write code that is hard-to-understand on purpose?  Describe what you are trying to do with that line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(cin >> A[i++]);
```

Will wait forever for the next input value until it encounters the end of the input or an invalid input value.

This will be working on hackerrank because they will be piping in a file with the input values so cin will report `eof` when you try to read too many values.

As you know exactly how many inputs you expect the easiest (and safest to prevent out of bounds array access) solution is to add s check for how many inputs you have read:

```
while(i < n && cin >> A[i++]);
```

Comment: I see, adding i < n worked on Xcode. Does Hackerrank hide the code where they read data from a file? I do not see any ofstream...open file etc..?

Comment: No they probably pipe the file into standard input